# Building a Java application with a Google Protocol Buffer JAR file

Tags: java, protocol-buffers, javac

I have a myprotofile.proto file that looks like this

```
 package PBPackage;
 message SomeMessage {
    required double someItem = 1;
 }
```

I build it like this (I'm on linux)

```
 JAVADIR=../../MyJarFile.jar
 protoc -I=. --java_out=${JAVADIR} myprotofile.proto
```

My Java program, Program.java, looks like this

```
 import PBPackage.SomeMessage;
 public class Program {
      public static void main( String[] args ){
           System.out.println( "this is my program" );
      }
  }
```

I try to build Program.java like this

```
 javac -cp .:MyJarFile.jar Program.java
```

But I always get this error:

```
 Program.java:1 error cannot find symbol
 import PBPackage.SomeMessage;
                 ^
 symbol:           class SomeMessage
 location:         package PBPackage
```

What am I doing wrong?

Finally, please don't tell me to use some overly complicated build system like ant or maven.

Comment: i think you should use semicolon to separate classpath entries `javac -cp .;MyJarFile.jar Program.java`

Comment: have you checked contents of your JAR file, is there SomeMessage class located in PBPackage folder?

Comment: Do I use `jar -xvz MyJarFile.jar` to check that?

Comment: Yes, you're right.  After looking in the JAR file I found that I really have to `import PBPackage.Myprotofile.SomeMessage`.  So it takes the filename, takes off the extension, capitalizes the first letter and then nowhere - that I found - does anything tell you that this is going on.  My next question is why does anyone use java and put up with this?!

Comment: If you want to answer the question with that I'll mark you right.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Most probably your JAR file contains this class in different package than you expect it.

There are two options you can use in your protobuf definition file to explicitly specify package and class name for generated code:

```
option java_package = "com.example.tutorial";
option java_outer_classname = "AddressBookProtos";
```

Please check [this tutorial](https://developers.google.com/protocol-buffers/docs/javatutorial) for more information.